# Get arguments in terminal to AppDelegate on flutter run

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I've been stuck for quite some time. I understand this may been asked and have searched as much as I could, so any guidance would be great.

I have a 3 schemes

- Debug-myapp-dev, Debug-myapp-uat, Debug-myapp-prod

When I click build `debug-myapp-prod` in Xcode, the logs say I am in `prod.`
When I run in terminal, the logs first say I am in `dev`, then I am in `prod`.

This is because in `main.dart` (just to test it out), I have

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  const MethodChannel channel = MethodChannel('app.myapp.channel');

// Pass the environment variable to iOS
  channel.invokeMethod('setEnvironment', {'flavor': 'prod'});
```

That means the initial one is reading dev in AppDelegate since that is the default, then gets value from flutter. That's not right.

Here's my AppDelegate

```
let args = CommandLine.arguments
                
        // Initialize a variable to store the environment ("env" or "flavor").
        var environment: String? = "dev"
        let plistFileName = "GoogleService-Info"
        
        
        let controller = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "app.myapp.channel", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)

        channel.setMethodCallHandler { [weak self] (call, result) in
            print ("in setMethodCall")
            if let arguments = call.arguments as? [String: Any], let flavor = arguments["flavor"] as? String {
                // 'flavor' now contains "prod"
                print("********************* FLAVA \(flavor)")
                environment = flavor;
            }
        }
let processInfo = ProcessInfo.processInfo
        for arg in processInfo.arguments {
            if arg.hasPrefix("--dart-define=") {
                let parts = arg.components(separatedBy: "=")
                if parts.count == 3 && parts[0] == "--dart-define" {
                    environment = parts[2]
                    print("Processing Info Environment: \(environment!)")
                    break 
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        print("========= Environment: \(environment!) ===============")

    
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "env/" + environment! + "/" + plistFileName, ofType: "plist") {
            print("Path: \(path)")
            let firbaseOptions = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: path) 
            FirebaseApp.configure(options: firbaseOptions!)
        } else {
            print("Plist file not found.")
            exit(0)
        }
```

I'm lost how do I get the `flutter run --flavor=myapp-prod --dart-define=flavor=prod  --target lib/main.dart` to get App Delegate to prod. It keeps initializing in dev in terminal. Therefore, my googleservice is not the correct file.

Where am I doing it wrong?